# drag and drop from master to detail view in sapui5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sapui5

I would like to enable drag and drop within an sapui5 app. To do so I'm using the jQuery draggable and droppable widgets. Whenever I'm dragging an element from the master view to the detail view or vise versa the dragged element is hiding behind the other view. The drop is still recognized, the element is just don't show up. Basically both views are just div's. It could have something to do with the *overflow* property but I'm not getting any sense into it.

I'm using those parameters on my draggable function:

```
draggable({
   helper: "clone",
   cancel: true,
   cursor: "pointer",
   stack: "
})
```

Here's a sample jsbin: http://jsbin.com/werewuf/4/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As the `sapMNav sapMSplitContainerMaster sapMSplitContainerMasterVisible` element having `overflow : hidden` property, any child of this parent can not be seen visible out of this container.

Set `'overflow' : 'visible'` for parent element and also for `dragButton.$().parent().css("overflow-y", "visible").css("overflow-x", "visible");`

```
$('.sapMSplitContainerMasterVisible').css('overflow', 'visible');
```

### [**JSBin Demo**](http://jsbin.com/paxuseyipi/1/edit?html,output)